# Python: list is populating with wrong order?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I have chain of 3 bones which are influenced by IK constraint. IK is added to bone named IK B#3: 
[image: chain of bones]

I'm trying to populate them into array in reverse order, i.e. **IK B#1, IK B#2, IK B#3 in that order**.

Code snipet:

```
bone_list = []

def populate_array(self):

    index = self.ik.chain_count - 1
    currentBone = activeBone
    for i in range(-1, self.ik.chain_count - 1):
        print("\nindex is :"+str(index)+"\n\tcurrent bone is: "+str(currentBone.name))
        self.bone_list.insert(index, currentBone)
        index -= 1
        currentBone = currentBone.parent

    #print out array
    for b in self.bone_list:
        print(b.name)
```

When i execute this code i'm getting this result:[image]

Why array is populated in that order, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: You should "append" to bone_list instead of "insert"

Comment: Uh, thanks! Write it as an answer so i could accept it.

Comment: and can you explain, what has been happening with my version.Why elements was inserted with that order? I don't get it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a general Python problem, not specific to blender, which will be more suited to one of the programming Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Since my question was related to blender scripting i decided to ask it here. Sorry if did something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not a Blender question, but anyway...

So use `append(currentBone)` instead of `insert(index, currentBone)`, to have `[IKB3, IKB2, IKB1]`.

Or use `insert(0, currentBone)` instead of `insert(index, currentBone)` to have `[IKB1, IKB2, IKB3]`.

But concerning "why" your usage of insert does not work:

## Step1:

`bone_list` is empty and index is `2`.

So `bone_list.insert(2, IKB3)` gives `bone_list = [IKB3]`. Explanation: Python tolerates that even if there is no element at position `2`.

And index becomes `1`.

## Step2:

`bone_list.insert(1, IKB2)` gives `bone_list = [IKB3, IKB2]`. Explanation: still no element at position `1` (IKB3 is at position `0`), so IKB2 is added at the end (which is the closest position to '1').

And index becomes `0`.

## Step3:

`bone_list.insert(0, IKB1)` gives `bone_list = [IKB1, IKB3, IKB2]`. Explanation: there is now an element at `0`, so as expected Python add IKB1 before it.